# What's the difference between term_id, term_taxonomy_id and cat_ID?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on a plugin and there I need `cat_ID`. I used this function,  `get_the_terms( $id,'category' );` and I am getting an array like this:

```
  Array
  (
     [10] => stdClass Object
         (
            [term_id] => 10
            [name] => Personal
            [slug] => personal
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 10
            [taxonomy] => category
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 3
            [object_id] => 1
            [filter] => raw
        )

 )
```

There should be a `cat_ID` but I can't find any.

It seems like `term_taxonomy_id` and `term_id` are showing what I'd expect to see in `cat_ID`, but somehow I came to know that sometimes `term_id` is different than `term_taxonomy_id`.

For example, if I delete a category and then create another, then the `term_id` will not be equal to `cat_ID`, will it?

Is it safe to use `term_taxonomy_id` as `cat_ID`? What's the difference between them all?

Comment: You can use term_id as cat_id

Comment: if i delete one category then create another then the term_id is not equal to cat_id. is it??

Answer (score 0):

`term_id` and `cat_ID` always have the same value. You aren't seeing category specific properties because you've used `get_the_terms()` instead of `get_the_category()`.

Change to `get_the_category( $id );`

Comment: The correct object is `cat_ID`, not `cat_id`. I always prefer to work with `get_terms` and `get_the_terms` are they are more flexible across a multi-taxonomy theme.

Comment: `get_categories()` is exactly the same as `get_terms('category')`